# Eclipse ADT Error when creating new Android Application Project

Tags: eclipse, adt

Excuse for my English wich isn't very good. I have a problem with Eclipse ADT when I want to create a new Android Application Project. I can see the first windows to enter the name ... then I can see the second Windows too but when I click on Next I have this error : Unhandled event loop exception and when I look in Error log I have this:

```
java.lang.InternalError
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.findSystemResourceBundle(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.findResourceBundle(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.setupResourceInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$SystemLoggerContext.demandLogger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.demandSystemLogger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getPlatformLogger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl.getLogger(Unknown Source)
    at sun.util.logging.LoggingSupport.getLogger(Unknown Source)
    at sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger$JavaLoggerProxy.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger$JavaLoggerProxy.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger.getLogger(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.createGraphics(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getGraphics(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.ImageUtils.createColoredImage(ImageUtils.java:973)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.assetstudio.ConfigureAssetSetPage.updateColor(ConfigureAssetSetPage.java:1240)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.assetstudio.ConfigureAssetSetPage.createControl(ConfigureAssetSetPage.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1246)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.access$4(WizardDialog.java:1238)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$8.run(WizardDialog.java:1227)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1225)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:915)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    ... 89 more
```

Here my SessionData:

```
eclipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
```

I try to reinstall the ADT Bundle but I've got the same error.
Can someone help me please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I finally found why doesn't work, the path of JRE installation was corrupted. I replace with good path and that work fine.